# Installation of semantic UI keeps failing

Tags: node.js, node-modules, semantic-ui

I am trying to install Semantic UI as a dependency in my project. I am getting this output in the terminal:

C:\Frontend setup>npm install semantic-ui@latest
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Frontend setup\node_modules\semantic-ui
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c gulp install
npm ERR! [09:34:55] Using gulpfile C:\Frontend setup\node_modules\semantic-ui\gulpfile.js
npm ERR! [09:34:55] Starting 'install'...
npm ERR!
[09:34:55] Starting 'run setup'...
npm ERR! ? Set-up Semantic UI (Use arrow keys)
npm ERR! > Automatic (Use default locations and all components)
npm ERR!   Express (Set components and output folder)
npm ERR!   Custom (Customize all src/dist values) [09:34:55] The following tasks did not complete: install, run setup
npm ERR! [09:34:55] Did you forget to signal async completion?

I've spent already a lot of time trying to figure out the issue, but I cannot seem to move past it.

My node version is 18.14.2

It throws first this error 1, but then it moves on like it is kind of prompting me to choose (which I guess it is what should normally happen).

Does anyone have a clue what is the problem here? According to the github repo, the latest version of semantic UI should be compatible with node 18. I have followed the instructions on their website carefully https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

Thanks!